# Is there an "async" mode for HTML5 video tag?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, gstreamer

I want to stream some videos from native C++ application to the browser. Currently, I'm using GStreamer to convert my content (e.g. captured from a camera) into a theroa ogg stream to a tcp server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=8080
```

Then I wrote a little `html5` page as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
      <source src="http://localhost:8080" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

  </body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that this `html5` video player is not a realtime video player. It always tries to buffer a small amount of streaming and play, causing a periodic pause. The buffered video will stay there and the total length of the video increases, and we can seek back to play the outdated content (we can see this by enabling the `controls` attribute in the `video` tag).

Thus, my question is: is there a "async mode" in the `html5` video player, so that it always plays the latest frame and ignore the history content, or I should look into something else to build this small live streaming service?

Comment: On an another note, I feel TCP is not useful for real time playing. Although it is more reliable, but it can induce latencies in case of retransmissions.  Try if you could use UDP instead.

Comment: Perhaps you could try with WebRTC, which is supported in GStreamer.

Comment: @vk_gst TCP can be fine for this... besides the connection in this case is over the loopback.  Better to use a straightforward protocol than to deal with the hassle of WebRTC.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments and help. There are definitely many ways to do it. Currently, I found a working alternative, which is able to broadcast videos from native C++ application to browsers. The idea is from this: https://phoboslab.org/log/2015/07/play-gta-v-in-your-browser-sort-of  It's using FFMpeg (encoding to MPEG1) + LibWebSockets (WebSocket and HTTP server)  + JSMpeg (in browser rendering), and I found the in-browser VNC idea itself is pretty interesting.

Comment: @Caili There's absolutely no need for the web-socket layer.  And, definitely no need for MPEG1... that's crazy.  You can stream directly from Gstream or FFmpeg straight over HTTP Progressive into a Video element, and with very low latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more control over buffering with Media Source Extensions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API

In this mode, you can stream live and completely discard all the old content.

It sounds to me though that you actually need a larger buffer... or more likely, more CPU.

Comment: Thank your very much for sharing it. I'm going to test it to see if I can make it work with my original purposed GStreamer + HTML5 video tag way.